# How to properly encode ID's in links and selects

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

(Working with CodeIgniter)

Hi there, thanks for reading me.

Quick question that I always stumble on while being in development...

How can I encode properly the IDs of the elements I'm showing on webpages... I want, on select change to show something else with Ajax in my main controller but I think that having the direct ID ( of the scope here ) staying there in my html is kind of wrong... Or am I wrong ?

For exemple, on selection a scope in here, I would load that scope, based on its ID, and show different information about it in the remaining of the page.

**[HTML]**

```
<select>
    <?php
    foreach ($scopes as $scope)
    {
    ?>
        <option value="<?=$scope->get_ScopeID();?>"><?=$scope->get_Name();?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

I've played a little bit with ajax, a good while with JQuery, no matter what website I look on, I can't seem to find the ID of the item I'm clicking on, so I concluded that I'm doing something wrong !

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exposing database items' IDs to the client is absolutely fine, and you're doing it right.

Take a look at this question's URL for example. 21561011 is the ID of the question in the database, and it's exposed to the client.

Comment: I would have thought that showing the ID was not a good practice. Thanks for the quick and clear answer !

Comment: @SantaClauss why would it not be? If coding is right, there's nothing anyone can do with that ID except pull up this question. Remove everything after 21561011 and it will still show the question.

Comment: @PanamaJack You're right that if at every action ( which everyone should ) you verify the rights of access of the user, nothing harmfull can be done.

This is the conclusion I came to, rather late I must say.

Thanks